# linux cd to folder containing the file

Tags: linux, terminal

Having a file path I would like to go to the directory of the file. A full path is like this:

```
/Users/user1/Documents/workspace/project/src/file.py
```

I would like in terminal to go the folder containing this file. 
In this case it would be:

```
/Users/user1/Documents/workspace/project/src/
```

Right now I have to paste the file in terminal, delete the file name and do cd. Like:

```
cd /Users/user1/Documents/workspace/project/src/
```

Is there a command/ any way I can skip deleting the file and use a smart command to know it should go to the directory containing this file?

I have to examine daily a lot of files and deleting the filename from path everytime is becoming a very tedious task.

The desired action would be something like this:

```
>>smart_cd /path/to/file.py
>>pwd
/path/to
```

Comment: Depends on the shell you are using, but in bash on Ubuntu, pressing `tab` autocompletes the folder name.

Comment: *"Having a file path (...)"* Where do you have this file path? Are you after some automated file editing script? Are the paths in a list of paths that you want to do something with? A little more info would be helpful.

Comment: @jDo the path is copied to clipboard.

Comment: Also sometimes drag the file from finder (mac) to terminal.

Comment: @apadana Cool cool. I think Chen Levy's solution looks good. It does require entering a command before copy/pasting the file name or dragging it into the window though. If only there was some way to evaluate what was currently written on the command line (without pressing enter) that could be tied to a keyboard short-cut. Hmm...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your are using Bash: You can put in your `~/.bashrc`

```
function smart_cd() {
    cd "$(dirname $1)"
}
```

then: (after re-loading your .bashrc)

```
$ smart_cd /Users/user1/Documents/workspace/project/src/file.py
```

---

**Bonus**: you can also replace your `cd` command to handle both normal and *smart* `cd`:

```
function cd() {
    if [ $# -eq 0 ] ; then
        # no arguments
        builtin cd
    elif [ -d $1 ] ; then
        # argument is a directory
        builtin cd "$1"
    else
        # argument is not a directory
        builtin cd "$(dirname $1)"
    fi
}
```

For more information see:

- *Special Parameters* in `man bash` for `$#`
- `man test` for explanation about `[ ... -eq ... ]` and `[ -d ... ]`

Comment: Wow! +1 for the Bonus! it's great to overwrite the cd command. Thanks.

Comment: I noticed if there is a space in the directory name the command fails. Is there any way to enhance so it can handle spaces in directory names? An example: cd /Volumes/NO\ NAME/DCIM

Comment: I edited my answer to add *double quotes* to deal with spaces in the input. You should note, though, that when calling the function you need to quote your spaces (as you did with `cd /Volumes/NO\ NAME/DCIM`), because otherwise the first argument `$1` will be assigned only the part before the white space, e.g. `/Volumes/NO`, and the `NAME/DCIM` will be assigned to `$2`. Also, using `$*` will not work if you have more than one space between words.

Answer (score 0):

This is Chen Levy’s Bonus above, but allows options for `cd` in addition (as `cd -P .` to resolve links), as well as links to files and folders.

```
function cd() {
    if [ $# -eq 0 ] ; then               # no arguments specified
        builtin cd
    elif [[ -f "$1" && -L "$1" ]] ; then # file, which is a link
       cd "$(readlink $1)"               # recursive
    elif [ -f $1 ] ; then                # argument is a file
       builtin cd "$(dirname $1)"
    else                                 # argument is not a file
       builtin cd "$@"
    fi
}
```